# Unable to access port 443 although it is open and listening

Tags: server, firewall, nginx, ssl, ufw

I'm trying to setup HTTPS on a website and already had configured everything needed on Nginx. But for some reason, although `netstat -tulpn` shows: 
[netstat result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXMq7.png) and ufw status is correct: [ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWcBw.png), i can't access the 443 port by telnet or any online port checker like: [port check result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtWiD.png).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you testing the port? Do you have a router or modem if yes, then you need to set up port forwarding there also to the machine with nginx.

Comment: i've tested using many sites (eg. https://www.portcheckers.com/) and using "telnet IP PORT" command from another machine. And no i don't have a router.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? Can you share the output of `sestatus` or `getenforce`?

Comment: Can you reach it on port 80? Also, have you tried reaching it locally, like a) from the server computer itself using https://127.0.0.1, b) from the server, but using its regular IP address (not 127.0.0.1), and c) from another computer on the same local network?

Comment: No, SELinux isn't enabled. I can reach the server on port 80 (it is serving a http website correctly). About questions a) and b): Connected successfully. I'm not able to test the third case right now.

Comment: Are You running only one web server at given time either `apache` or `nginx` ?